# Trying to figure out how to switchMap an Organization to a Base in an Angular Component

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs, switchmap

So I have an API that I am trying to consume data from. The data being retuned:

**Org**

```
baseId: 1
createdAt: "2018-11-14T04:35:35.345Z"
id: 1
isActive: true
orgName: "Test Organization 1"
orgOwner: 2
subscriptionCode: "testorg1"
updatedAt: "2018-11-14T04:35:35.34
```

**Base**

```
bandwidthApiSecret: "xxxxxx"
bandwidthApiToken: "t-xxxxxx"
bandwidthUserId: "u-xxxxxx"
baseName: "Test AFB 1"
basePhoneNumber: "+18442367381"
createdAt: "2018-11-14T04:35:35.123Z"
id: 1
isActive: true
updatedAt: "2018-11-14T04:35:35.123Z"
```

What I would like to do, but fail to comprehend is using rxjs operations to insert the organization where needed. So if a base has one or more organizations it should be inserted into the bases. Here are my interfaces:

**Base Interface**

```
import { Organization } from './organization';
import { BaseManager } from './base-manager';

export interface Base {
    id: number;
    basePhoneNumber: string;
    baseName: string;
    bandwidthUserId: string;
    bandwidthApiToken: string;
    bandwidthApiSecret: string;
    createdAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
    orgs?: Organization;
    managers?: BaseManager;
}
```

**Org Interface**

```
export interface Organization {
    id: number;
    orgName: string;
    orgOwner: string;
    baseId: number;
    subscriptionCode: string;
    isActive: boolean;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
}
```

I found this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/batuzaq/edit?js,console) that sort of looks like it's doing what I need to accomplish. Due to my lack of comprehension of the subject I am failing to make it work. Here's a snippet of my Angular Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Base } from 'src/app/core/interfaces/base';
import { BaseService } from 'src/app/core/services/base.service';
import { OrgService } from 'src/app/core/services/org.service';
import { Organization } from 'src/app/core/interfaces/organization';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base-list',
  templateUrl: './base-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base-list.component.css']
})
export class BaseListComponent implements OnInit {

  bases: Base[];
  orgs: Organization[];

  constructor(private baseService: BaseService, private orgService: OrgService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadOrgs();
    this.loadBases();
  }

  loadBases() {
    this.baseService.getAllBases()
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.bases = res['bases'];
          console.log(this.bases);
        }
      );
  }
  // loadBases(): Base[] {
  //   this.baseService.getAllBases()
  //     .subscribe(
  //       res => {
  //         this.bases = res['bases'].pipe(
  //           switchMap( base => {
  //             return this.getOrg(base.id).map(
  //               base => {
  //                 return Object.assign(base, {base, {org: this.orgs});
  //               }
  //             )
  //           })
  //         );
  //       });
  // }

  loadOrgs() {
    this.orgService.getOrgs()
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.orgs = res['orgs'];
          console.log(this.orgs);
        }
      );
  }

  getOrg(baseId) {
    this.bases.filter(base => base.id === baseId);
  }

}
```

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Coach

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues: First, `res['bases']` is not an Observable and therefore can't be piped. This function invocation is not possible:

```
res['bases'].pipe(...)
```

Second, you are trying to assign the Observable to the property `this.bases` which has the type `Base[]` and not `Observable<Base[]>`. The assignment would therefore not be valid.

Third, even if `res['bases']` were an Observable, you are never subscribing to it, so it won't ever emit any notifications.

The solution is one the one hand to not subscribe before the `switchMap`, but afterwards and on the other hand to correctly handle the array collection, e.g. with `zip`. This is how it would look like:

```
this.baseService.getAllBases().pipe(
        switchMap(bases =>
            zip(...bases.map(base =>
                    this.getOrg(base.id).pipe(
                        map(base => Object.assign(base, {orgs: this.orgs}))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ).subscribe(bases =>
        this.bases = bases
    )
```

Now, another issue is that you aren't waiting for `loadOrgs` to compete before trying to load the bases. This should also be concatenated like this:

```
loadOrgs(): Observable<Organization[]> {
    return this.orgService.getOrgs().pipe(
        tap(
            res => {
                this.orgs = res['orgs'];
                console.log(this.orgs);
            }
        )
    )
}
```

And in `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadOrgs().subscribe(() => {
        this.loadBases();
    });
}
```

As a rule of thumb, be sure to **always subscribe** to your Observables, otherwise you won't actually execute anything. There are some pipes that do subscribe to inner Observables, like `switchMap`, but there must actually be a Subscriber for the `switchMap` pipe as well in order for it to take effect.

Comment: ggradnig - Wow! Thank you so much for giving me a well put together comment! I will try your suggestions and report back. Again, your advice is very much appreciated!